# If the dissertation defense is completed and passed prior to the completion of the program classes, is the student considered a Doctor?

Tags: phd, coursework, education, defense

Courses not passed or taken but dissertation and defense completed with approval/passing.

Comment: That depends on the local rules. All requirements need to be met, however.

Comment: In my experience, in the US, it's common for the committee to congratulate the PhD candidate and call them "Doctor" after a successful defense even if there are additional corrections to the dissertation required or the student has coursework to complete.  That doesn't mean that the degree has been awarded, and it would be unwise for the new PhD to claim that the degree had been completed until the degree is officially confirmed.

Comment: I have never heard of completing a defense before required classes.  Usually defense occurs after candidacy, which occurs after classes.

Comment: @Buffy You claim it depends on local rules, and then you said the title is awarded when all requirements are met.  This seems contradictory.  I greatly doubt there are any places where titles are awarded before the requirements for the title are met, so local rules do not vary.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, yes of course the local rules vary. I had two requirements for the doctorate: pass comps and write an acceptable dissertation. I could still take courses but they were irrelevant to whether I earned the degree or not. OTOH, some places may require passing specific courses.

Comment: @Buffy I think it's 100% clear from context that the question is about required courses.

Comment: Furthermore, even if the courses are optional, the answer to the question is the same:  You get the title when the degree is awarded, and no sooner.

Comment: Considered by whom for what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Formally, only use the title when the degree is awarded.  Coursework and defenses do not determine titles.  Degrees do.

Informally, it does not matter.